# Running a SQL query on pyspark streaming dataframe

Tags: pyspark

How do I run a SQL query on Pyspark streaming dataframe?

```
df = spark.readStream.format('delta').table(table_name)
```

When I run `df.count()`, I get an an error

> Queries with streaming sources must be executed with `writeStream.start()`